# Open local file with query params (Using Chrome and Powershell)

Tags: powershell, file, google-chrome, local

I need to launch a local application (it needs some parameters in the query string) with Chrome and Powershell.

This is what I'm trying, but it doesn't work.

```
$MediaName = "Test_Media"

$CurrentLocation = Get-Location

$PreviewTemplateLocation = "$($CurrentLocation.Drive.Name):\\Work\_all\Tools\Script\MCD\Script\template"
$TemplateIndexLocation = Join-Path -Path $PreviewTemplateLocation -ChildPath "index.html"

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe", "$($TemplateIndexLocation)`#media=$($MediaName) --incognito --disable-web-security --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=C:/chromeTemp")
```

The url should be

C:\Work_all\Tools\Script\MCD\Script\template\index.html#media=Test_Media

but what I get is

C:\Work_all\Tools\Script\MCD\Script\template\index.html%23media=Test_Media

Note that I get %23 instead of # in the URL. Shouldn't the # character be escaped or something like that?

Thank you!!

Comment: As an aside: `$($CurrentLocation.Drive.Name)` can be simplified to `$($PWD.Drive.Name)`, using the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd), whose value is the same as `Get-Location`'s return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a regular file-system path, Chrome automatically escapes URL metacharacters such as `#` for you (`%23` is the escaped form of `#`).

Use the `file://` protocol to avoid this escaping (`file:///` to specify a *local* path).
Additionally, you can use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) instead of `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start()`, for a more PowerShell-idiomatic experience.

```
Start-Process chrome "file:///$TemplateIndexLocation#media=$MediaName --incognito --disable-web-security --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=C:/chromeTemp"
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SebastianBernardotti; my pleasure.